# Logistic regression: Trying to use mean logit as reference group

Tags: regression, logistic, categorical-encoding, contrasts

## Question

I would like to do a logistic regression where the independent variables are compared to the mean logit, rather than the logit being compared a certain reference group.

## Example

The example below results in the logit of am==1 is being compared to carb==1 (the reference group):

```
glm( am==1  ~    factor(carb),    data = mtcars, family = binomial )
```

Is it possible (and does it make sense?) to compare the logit of am==1, to the mean logit, instead of comparing it to carb==1

Hope this makes sense :)

Comment: Sounds like you want sum-to-zero coding, [here](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/library/contrast_coding.htm#DEVIATION) called deviation coding.

Comment: Thanks, I believe that's what I was looking for. If you post as answer I shall accept.